# Мусор при выводе массива вложенного в структуру

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Всем привет. У меня дано задание: описать структуру note в которой содержатся следующие поля: Имя, Фамилия, номер телефона, дата рождения(массив из 3 чисел). Последнее является обязательным условием. Я описал структуру, сделал ввод и вывод. Всё работает, но все записи кроме последней в году рождения имеют странное значение отличное от вводимого. Прикрепляю к вопросу экран вывода и код.[image: вывод]

```
// Struct_simpled.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;


struct note
{
char name[30];
char sec_name[50];
char phone[15];
int date[3];
};
note point[3];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) //ввод структуры
{
    cout << "input the Name (30 char's)" << endl;
    cin >> point[i].name;
    cout << "input the second name (50 char's)" << endl;
    cin >> point[i].sec_name;
    cout << "input phone number (15 characters)" << endl;
    cin >> point[i].phone;
    cout << "input the date of birthday" << endl;
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        cin >> point[i].date[j];
    }
}


for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) // вывод структуры
{
    cout << point[i].name << "  " << point[i].sec_name << "  " <<                         point[i].phone << "  ";

    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        cout << point[i].date[j]<<".";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: почему и из-за чего происходит замусоривание последнего элемента целочисленного массива date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массивы в C++ индексируются с 0.

`int date[3]` - это элементы `date[0]`,  `date[1]` и `date[2]`.

Вы же работаете, начиная с 1:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
{
    cout << point[i].date[j]<<".";
}
```

должно на самом деле выглядеть как

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    cout << point[i].date[j]<<".";
}
```

И не только это - вы и к элементам массива `node point[3];` обращаетесь неправильно.

Даже странно, что при таком явном выходе за границы массива у вас не завершилась аварийно... Это вам не повезло.

Comment: Хорошо, а как обращаться к структуре правильно? Просто я такого нюанса не знаю даже. Нам тупо дали пачку заданий и сказали писать - всё, но это уже лирическое отступление

UPD 
Кажется понял в чем юмор касательно node point

Comment: Да просто замените все циклы, как я показал в ответе - на цикл от 0 до 2.

Comment: Кстати ещё я забыл в Char'ах про нуль-символы! Так что нужно на них накинуть по 1 символу.